# Why is datagrid raising exception when loosing focus?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, exception, datagrid

I think I have found a bug in DataGrid. I get an seemingly unexplainable crash with the datagrid in WPF (.net 5.0)

Can you spot what I do wrong? I cannot... I spent so many days on this now and the code is very clear.

How to crash:

1. build and run code given below.
2. Edit the "data" grid cell, leave cursor in cell textbox
3. select update from menu. (the cell will revert to "data")
4. edit the "data" grid cell again, leave cursor in cell textbox
5. click on "tabitem" header -> **exception** shown below:

```
System.ArgumentNullException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'element')
  Source=PresentationCore
  StackTrace:
   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.UIElementAutomationPeer.FromElement(UIElement element)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.CellAutomationValueHolder.TrackValue()
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.ReleaseCellAutomationValueHolders()
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.OnExecutedCommitEdit(ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.OnExecutedCommitEdit(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.CommandBinding.OnExecuted(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.FindCommandBinding(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e, ICommand command, Boolean execute)
   at System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.OnExecuted(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnExecutedThunk(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand.ExecuteImpl(Object parameter, IInputElement target, Boolean userInitiated)
   at System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand.Execute(Object parameter, IInputElement target)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.EndEdit(RoutedCommand command, DataGridCell cellContainer, DataGridEditingUnit editingUnit, Boolean exitEditMode)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.OnCurrentCellChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetCurrentValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.set_CurrentCellContainer(DataGridCell value)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.set_FocusedCell(DataGridCell value)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell.OnAnyLostFocus(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnLostFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.TextBoxBase.OnLostFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.TextBox.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.ClearValueCommon(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.ClearValue(DependencyPropertyKey key)
   at System.Windows.Input.FocusManager.OnFocusedElementChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
   at System.Windows.Input.FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(DependencyObject element, IInputElement value)
   at System.Windows.Input.KeyboardNavigation.UpdateFocusedElement(DependencyObject focusTarget)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnGotKeyboardFocus(Object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.ChangeFocus(DependencyObject focus, Int32 timestamp)
   at System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.Focus(DependencyObject focus, Boolean askOld, Boolean askNew, Boolean forceToNullIfFailed)
   at System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.Focus(IInputElement element)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Focus()
   at System.Windows.Controls.TabItem.SetFocus()
   at System.Windows.Controls.TabItem.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at datagridcrashtest2.App.Main()
```

Source code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;


namespace DataGridTest
{
    public class DataGridTest 
    {
      
        static string xaml = @"
<Window x:Class=""System.Windows.Window"" 
        xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation""
        xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml""
        xmlns:d=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008""
        xmlns:mc=""http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006""
        mc:Ignorable=""d""
        Title=""DataGridTest"" Height=""650"" Width=""925"">
    <StackPanel >

        <Menu>
            <MenuItem Header=""File"" >
                <MenuItem Header=""Save"" Command=""{Binding UpdateCommand}"" />
                <Button Command=""{Binding UpdateCommand}"" Content=""Update"" />
            </MenuItem>
            <Button Command=""{Binding UpdateCommand}"" Content=""Update"" />
        </Menu>

        <TabControl >
            <TabItem Header=""TabItem"" Width=""150"" DataContext=""{Binding TabItemViewModel}"" >
                <DataGrid ItemsSource=""{Binding DataListViewModel}"" />
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>

    </StackPanel>
</Window>";

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            var window = Xaml.LoadXaml<Window>(xaml);
            window.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
            window.ShowDialog();
        }
    }

    public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModel
    {
        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            TabItemViewModel = new TabItemViewModel();
            UpdateCommand = new Command(Update);
        }

        public TabItemViewModel TabItemViewModel { get; set; }
        public ICommand UpdateCommand { get; set; }

        public void Update()
        {
            TabItemViewModel.Update();
        }
    }

    public class TabItemViewModel : ViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<DataViewModel> DataListViewModel { get; set; } =
            new ObservableCollection<DataViewModel>();

        public TabItemViewModel()
        {
            Update();
        }
        
        public void Update()
        {
            DataListViewModel = new ObservableCollection<DataViewModel>(); 

            DataListViewModel.Add( new DataViewModel() { Name = "data" });
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(DataListViewModel));
        }
    }

    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #region MVVM

    public class DataViewModel : ViewModel
    {
        private string name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                if (name != value)
                {
                    name = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.Name));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Command : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Action action;
        public Command(Action action)
        {
            this.action = action;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            action();
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    }
    #endregion

    public class Xaml
    {
        public static T LoadXaml<T>(string xaml)
        {
            using (var stringReader = new System.IO.StringReader(xaml))
            using (var xmlReader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(stringReader))
                return (T)System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is a sure way to trigger the crash mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68028285/c-sharp-wpf-datagrid-commitedit-throws-exception-with-value-cannot-be-null-par